# Diferença entre o evento (submit) e (ngSubmit)

Tags: angular

Bom, vi alguns artigos explicando que o "ngSubmit garante que o formulário não é enviado quando o código do manipulador é lançado (que é o comportamento padrão de envio) e causa uma solicitação de postagem http real."

Sinceramente não entendi nada.

Qual é a diferença entre esses dois eventos?

Comment: submit causa postBack, ou seja, recarrega a página. ngSubmit basicamente impede o compartamento padrão do submit, tendo maior controle em uma aplicação SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na tradução que você mencionou. O trecho original diz:

> ngSubmit ensures that the form doesn’t submit when the handler code throws (which is the default behaviour of submit) and causes an actual http post request.

A parte que importa é `"handler code throws"`, isso se refere à exceptions, exemplo:

```
if (this.formControls.sellingDate > today) {
    throw new Error("Campo data não pode ser maior que hoje.");
}
```

A tradução `"é lançado"` realmente não é uma boa tradução para `"throws"`, e é onde está causando dúvidas.

No entanto, não aconselho você a validar formulários usando exceptions, tente usar `Validators` nos seus formControls ou então até mesmo usar `toastr` para notificar o usuário sobre o problema com os dados informados de forma mais amigável.

Outro ponto é que para evitar reloads, caso esse seja seu problema, você tem duas opções que eu considero melhor:

- passar o `$event` pro seu método (`"handler"`) e chamar `$event.preventDefault();` logo na primeira linha; ou
- quando entrar num "if" que seja impeditivo, usar `return false;` logo depois de dar a mensagem ao usuário.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

A parte final do comportamento padrão do evento `Submit()` de um formulário é o envio do conteúdo do formulário para o destino especificado no atributo `action`, seguindo de uma recarga da página.

Esta recarga vai contra o comportamento desejado em uma aplicação de página única - no caso sua aplicação Angular deve apenas enviar o conteúdo e aguardar o retorno sem *reload*.

Comment: Sim, mas no Angular2+ existem dois eventos, o submit e o ngSubmit. Os dois submetem os dados e os dois não recarregam a página. Queria saber a diferença entre esses events binding